# How to change the transparent background color of an image in css?

Tags: html, css

[Shrimp image with transparent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N75QK.png)

So I have an image of a shrimp with a transparent background. Meaning that when i render it it supposed to only show the shrimp and not the transparent background. I'm trying to render it in a webpage using html and css. How can I render the image in my webpage and making sure that the transparent background doesn't show it becomes transparent and shows whatever is behind the image other than the shrimp itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the background in your image is NOT transparent, it's just look like...

Answer (score 1):

Your image is a PNG file but it does not have a transparent background. Try to use photoshop to remove the background. :)